# python global name is not defined issue using classes

Tags: python, class

I am creating a class of customer shopping carts so I have created a class of products and then shopping basket with methods to add, remove and empty basket.
Now I want to calculate price total of a basket with a BOGOF offer.
My problem is with the 'total' method, the error is 'global name x is not defined'.

My problem is I need to code in that the things in the cart are the name attributes of the instances of the class of products. I couldn't figure out another way to append products to a 'cart' or list so hopefully I haven't erred there. I don't understand why there is an error here but not in the 'additems' method where I used item.quantity.

My guess is that the difference is that item was part of the domain of the function but x isn't. I don't think I need any other inputs to my total method. I just need self because every self has a basket, which is all I need.

Thank you for your help

```
class products:
  def __init__(self,name,price,quantity):
    self.price=price
    self.quantity=quantity
self.productname=name



class ShoppingBasket:
  def __init__(self,name,basket=[]):
    self.name=name
    self.basket=basket[:]






def additems(self,*items):

for item in items: 

    if item.quantity>0:

      self.basket.append(item.productname)
      item.quantity-=1
      print  "%s has been added to %s's basket"%(item.productname, self.name)
    else:
      print "sorry item is not in stock"



  def removeitems(self,*items):

for item in items:
  if item.productname in self.basket:
    self.basket.remove(item.productname)
    item.quantity+=1

    print "%s has been removed from %s's basket"%(item.productname,self.name) 
  else: print "not in basket"


  def empty(self):
    self.basket[:]=[]
    print "%s's basket is empty"%(self.name)

  def total(self):
    total=0

    for x.productname in self.basket:
      z=[s for s in self.basket if s==x.productname ]
      if len(z)%2==0: 
        price=x.price*(len(z)/2)
      else: 
        price=x.price*(len(z)//2)+item.price
      total+=price
    return total
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the code indentation

Comment: `'global name x is not defined'` means that the name `x` is not defined. If you look through your code, you'll see that you indeed do not define it anywhere.

Comment: @cricket_007 should be fine within a `class` definition. Not that I'd recommend it, but that's not the problem here.

Comment: @cricket_007 unless `total` is a method in a class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't iterate over attributes within a loop like this

```
for x.productname in self.basket:
```

You must assign the object, then get it.

```
for x in self.basket:
    z=[s for s in self.basket if s==x.productname]
```

I'm not following that logic, but it seems a very inefficient way to total all the products in the basket.

For example, this will add all the prices of the items in the basket

```
return sum(x.price for x in self.basket)
```

Note: `item` is also undefined in the loop

To implement a BOGOF offer, I would suggest trying *not adding* an item to the basket if it already exists, although that might work out poorly for buying more than two of the same item.
My point is, only one line is really needed to calculate the total, as shown.  The logic to only maintain an odd number of items to total can be done while the items are added to the basket

Comment: well the item loop works weirdly. So how do I assign the object? Also bear in mind I need to count number of duplicates because of bogof. Maybe that is what is inefficient

Comment: Assign what object? You have Product objects in a list. Iterating over that will assign one object to loop variable. From the loop variable, you treat it as any other object... I don't see why you care about duplicates, e.g. if you have something twice, you still pay for both

Comment: If you want to truly tally the Product amounts, you probably would use a dictionary, not a list. `{'milk':2, 'dozen_eggs':3}`

Comment: See my answer. I found a way through.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to make it work guys. I've defined a new attribute: secretbasket to hold all class instances and basket holds their names (for the benefit of the consumer). My function now works and handles BOGOF!

```
def total(self):
    total=0
    for x in self.secretbasket:
        z=[s for s in self.secretbasket if s==x]

        if len(z)%2==0:
            price=x.price*(len(z)/2)
            self.secretbasket=[s for s in self.secretbasket if s!=x ]
        else: 
            price=x.price*(len(z)//2)+x.price
            self.secretbasket=[s for s in self.secretbasket if s!=x ]
        print price
        total+=price
    return total
```

Comment: Your indentation is still off

Comment: A mere trifle. When I copy and paste it messes up. Still readable

Comment: Man you didn't need to edit. I don't mean for other to clean up my mess.